# Get the lastest record with distinct values for a column

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-4

I have the following data:

```
SalesID Source  Name    Modified On
S12345  ABC John    5/8/2013 5:44
S12345  ABC Tom 5/8/2013 5:45
S11111  EFG Sam 5/8/2013 5:46
S11111  EFG Don 5/8/2013 5:47
```

I want to write a SP or a query that will return me the 2nd and the 4th row i.e I want to write a query that will return the lasted modified records based on distinct sales ID.

Answer (score 0):

i used the following query and it worked just fine for me

```
    SELECT * FROM  (Select Asu_OrderId ,ModifiedOn ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Asu_OrderId order by ModifiedOn desc)AS R from Asu_callreason 
where <condition>) AS A  WHERE r=1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following:**

```
select * from tableName where ModifiedOn=(select max(ModifiedOn) from tableName) group by SalesID
```